# Meteor npm get request ECONNRESET

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, request

I am using following method for uploading to S3 bucket in Meteor. I do get request, and if there is response, I upload it to S3 bucket. I have around 700 URLs like that. I do HTTP GET request for each URL, and try to upload to S3. The main problem is that at the very beginning, for about 150 files I am getting following error:

```
I20170725-22:22:39.344(2)? An error occured during upload:  { [Error: 
connect ECONNRESET https://pushmetrics.com:443]
I20170725-22:22:39.344(2)?   code: 'ECONNRESET',
I20170725-22:22:39.344(2)?   errno: 'ECONNRESET',
I20170725-22:22:39.345(2)?   syscall: 'connect',
I20170725-22:22:39.345(2)?   address: 'https://pushmetrics.com',
I20170725-22:22:39.345(2)?   port: 443
```

After that it works for other files. Only first 150 URLs are failing.

```
uploadToS3: (url, headers, connectionId, itemId, itemName, type) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.get({
            url: url,
            headers: headers,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {  
                reject(error);
            } else {
                // Create S3 service object
                var s3 = new AWS.S3();
                // bucketName var below crates a "folder" for each item
                var bucketName = '/connections/' + connectionId + '/' + type + '/' + itemId + '/';
                var params = {
                    Bucket: Meteor.settings.private.s3.bucket,
                    Key: bucketName + itemName + '.png',
                    Body: body,
                    ContentType: 'image/png',
                    ACL: 'public-read'
                };
                s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(`Error during upload file ${params.Key} to S3: ${err}"`);
                        return res.status(500).send(err)
                    };
                    let s3Url = data.Location;
                    resolve(s3Url)
                });
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Method uploadToS3 is invoked by following async method:

```
uploadItemToS3: async (url, headers, connectionId, itemId, itemName, type) => {
    s3Url = await Api.uploadToS3(url, headers, connectionId, itemId, itemName, type);
    return s3Url;
}
```

Comment: are you behind some sort of proxy?

Comment: no, I am not behind the proxy. When the program starts it fails for the first 150 URLs and after some time it generates responses from those URLs. These URLs are just links to thumbnails on my server. I do GET request with such URL and try upload to S3 bucket. No clue why it does not work at the beginning. I guess it is too much for the server to receive so many requests?